# ESXI Configuring windows VM in different subnet

Tags: esxi

I'm newbie in ESXI, and i have to create a windows VM, with a different subnet than the main LAN
my problem is when i use the ip config of the main LAN i haven't any probem, everything is alright, but i don't know how to use a different LAN for my VM and make it communicate with my main LAN,

I've been searching in many forums and KB, i saw that i must configure ports group, static route, Vswitches, ...

But i haven't find any step by step tutorial to do that.

can anyone help me ?

thanks.

i'm newbie in esxi and actually i can only make it run alright in the same lan
i tried to configure a port group , a vSwitch, a VMK NIC, but i not reached to connect my
vSwitch to physical NIC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjYju.png)